# can't access data from php to angularJs

Tags: php, angularjs

I'm trying to get the value for my list content from the database and php must be called when The content is loaded it looks something like this

```
<form ng-controler="contr">
    <select  onload="load_data()" ng-reapet="d in data">
      <option >{{d.name}} </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

and my controller is

```
  .controller('contr',function($scope,$http)
  {
    $scope.load_data =function()
    {
      alert(data);

         $http({
                    method  : 'GET',
                    url     : 'php/crop_cat.php',
                    headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                        $scope.data=data;
                        alert(data);
                    })
    }
  });
```

and my php is working fine if i render $data its giving me correct data format, and no connection error

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconnect.php';
$test_arr=mysqli_query($con,'select id,name from test');
$data=array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($test_arr)){
    $data[]=$row;
}
print json_encode($data);
?>
```

please help me. Thank you

Comment: so your  `$http({ ..` is wrong. please check url and other things.

Comment: I double checked their is no such issues @SSH

Comment: what does `onload="load_data()"` supposed to do? why do you have in your view `ng-controler="contr"` while you're showing us the `crop_cat` controller code? where do you call `$scope.load_crop()`? every line in this code is just wrong!

Comment: While posting this question i did some changes to the html and I did't do it for the controller I will edit it soon

Comment: so now you just need to remove the `onload="load_data()"` from the view, and in your controller, remove the function `$scope.load_data =function() { .... }` and just put the code directly in the controller. If it will work, you'll probably see multiple selects as the server return the results

Comment: ya thanks i got it..